# casting object from XSSFWorkbook and SXSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, apache-poi

I use a template file containing 2 tables on first sheet. I need to perform 2 operations on first sheet.

1. There is Locations data table column headers(ex. sr.no, Location and related data fields) in which I need to use XSSFWorkbook so that I may shift rows down according to size of locations.
2. There is Devices Table, in which I need to use streaming api i.e. SXSSFWorkbook object

I created workbook object using XSSFWorkbook, shifted rows down and then tried to cast workbook into SXSSFWorkbook. But it throws error while in execution

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempting to write a row[11] in the range [0,30] that is already written to disk.
```

If I first create workbook obj using SXSSFWorkbook, it is not possible to create
XSSFWorkbook from it. Can someone please suggest how it can be done.

I tried :

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
// First shift rows down - WORKS FINE
sheet.shiftRows( tab1HeaderRowNum + 1, sheet.getLastRowNum(), locationRecordsSize - 1);
// Copy style of row on new rows -  WORKS FINE
for(int i = 1; i < locationRecordsSize; i++){
    sheet.copyRows(tab1HeaderRowNum , tab1HeaderRowNum , (tab1HeaderRowNum + i), cellCopyPolicy);
}
// Create new SXSSFWorkbook
SXSSFWorkbook sxssfWorkbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(workbook);
SXSSFSheet sxssfSheet = sxssfWorkbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
if(sxssfSheet.getRow(rowNum) == null){  // rowNum is of row which is newly added using shiftRows
        row = sxssfSheet.createRow(rowNum); // Error Occurs Here
    }else{
        row = sxssfSheet.getRow(rowNum);
    }
```

Im using Apache POI 3.15

Comment: This approach is not possible [public SXSSFWorkbook(XSSFWorkbook workbook)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html#SXSSFWorkbook-org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook-): " What is not supported: Access initial cells and rows in the template....".

Comment: Thnx Axel. Now Im writing all template components using SXSSF.